# Grouping Excel charts in a Word document

Tags: microsoft-word, charts, microsoft-word-2013

I have some Excel charts that I've pasted into Word, and I would like to group them together so they move as a unit as I'm moving text around.

Currently, they look like this:
[image]

(forgive the rough edges, I need to align them a bit)

When I highlight them and I try to select Group, it's blurred out.  I'm assuming, then, that it only works for inserted pictures and not Excel graphs.

[image]

Is there a way in Word to group these charts together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want is to group them so they move together you can insert the graphs inside of a textbox.  Turn off the border and set fill to none.  Now you essentially have a group of charts that move together.

[image]